# How come my array loads but my tableView will crash with index beyond bounds for empty array?

Tags: ios, objective-c

This is my error:

```
-[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 12 beyond bounds for empty array
```

I know this error means I'm trying to access an "empty array".

This error only happens in viewX when it is popped back from viewY. When you press 'back button' on navigation bar in viewY and scroll the tableView immediately, it will crash and cause this error. I am using the [RETableViewManager](https://github.com/romaonthego/RETableViewManager) to load my tableView.

In viewX's viewDidLoad:

```
[[RACSignal combineLatest:@[RACObserve(self, record), RACObserve(self, restaurant)]] subscribeNext:^(id x) {
       [self setupItems];
    }];
```

in setupItems:

```
RecordManager *recordManager = [[EZRecordManager alloc] initWithRecord:self.record restaurant:self.restaurant sender:self.navigationController];
self.items = [recordManager items];
self.section = [RETableViewSection section];
[self.items each:^(id data) {
    if ([data isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
        self.navigationItem.title = (NSString *)data;
    } else {
        [self registerItem:[data class]];
        [self.section addItem:data];
    }
}];

[self.manager addSection:self.section];
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

I NSLogged my array 'self.items'. and this is what logs according to the method:

```
viewDidAppear - (
"\U5df2\U8a02\U4f4d\Uff0c\U5c1a\U672a\U7528\U9910",
"<REReservationHeaderItem: 0x14015b0b0>",
"<REAttributedStrItem: 0x14015b1b0>",
"<REAttributedStrWithNextItem: 0x140191a70>",
"<REAttributedStrItem: 0x140193f60>",
"<RESpacerItem: 0x140194870>",
"<REAttributedStrWithNextItem: 0x14019ce10>",
"<REAttributedStrItem: 0x140199230>",
"<RESpacerItem: 0x1401a04e0>",
"<REActionItem: 0x14019e490>",
)
```

The NSLog logs the same array in setupItems so I know the array is still there because self.item is saved as a property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *items;
```

So this algorithm works as expected when I'm loading viewX for the first time, but as soon as I go into another view(viewY) and press the 'back button' on viewY to pop to viewX and then immediately scroll, it crashes with the above error. If I wait for a second (maybe even half a second), viewX will work properly and have no issue. I know this is minor but my PM is stressing that this shouldn't happen. How can I solve this problem?

The method the error occurs in (part of the RETableViewManager library):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

{
    RETableViewSection *section = [self.mutableSections objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    RETableViewItem *item = [section.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

```
UITableViewCellStyle cellStyle = UITableViewCellStyleDefault;
if ([item isKindOfClass:[RETableViewItem class]])
    cellStyle = ((RETableViewItem *)item).style;

NSString *cellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"RETableViewManager_%@_%li", [item class], (long) cellStyle];

Class cellClass = [self classForCellAtIndexPath:indexPath];

if (self.registeredXIBs[NSStringFromClass(cellClass)]) {
    cellIdentifier = self.registeredXIBs[NSStringFromClass(cellClass)];
}

if ([item respondsToSelector:@selector(cellIdentifier)] && item.cellIdentifier) {
    cellIdentifier = item.cellIdentifier;
}

RETableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

void (^loadCell)(RETableViewCell *cell) = ^(RETableViewCell *cell) {
    cell.tableViewManager = self;

    // RETableViewManagerDelegate
    //
    if ([self.delegate conformsToProtocol:@protocol(RETableViewManagerDelegate)] && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(tableView:willLoadCell:forRowAtIndexPath:)])
        [self.delegate tableView:tableView willLoadCell:cell forRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    [cell cellDidLoad];

    // RETableViewManagerDelegate
    //
    if ([self.delegate conformsToProtocol:@protocol(RETableViewManagerDelegate)] && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(tableView:didLoadCell:forRowAtIndexPath:)])
        [self.delegate tableView:tableView didLoadCell:cell forRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
};

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[cellClass alloc] initWithStyle:cellStyle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    loadCell(cell);
}

if ([cell isKindOfClass:[RETableViewCell class]] && [cell respondsToSelector:@selector(loaded)] && !cell.loaded) {
    loadCell(cell);
}

cell.rowIndex = indexPath.row;
cell.sectionIndex = indexPath.section;
cell.parentTableView = tableView;
cell.section = section;
cell.item = item;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = nil;

if ([item isKindOfClass:[RETableViewItem class]])
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = ((RETableViewItem *)item).detailLabelText;

[cell cellWillAppear];

return cell;
```

}

Comment: so where does the error occur? post that piece of code

Comment: Is there a line of code to (re-)initialize the array or remove all objects? It seems to be a timing issue of an asynchronous method.

Comment: @AndreyChernukha the error occurs in the library. -[RETableViewManager tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]

Comment: @vadian, I think so as well. I think (I'm maintaining someone else's code) this line reinitiates the array. self.items = [recordManager items];

Comment: Can you post the tableview delegate methods?

Comment: @EricChuang the line reassigns something to the array and `viewDidLoad` is only called once. What happens in `viewWill/DidAppear`?

Comment: The UI related updates should be done in main queue, but from your code I can make the the method setupItems: in which reloadData is called is not in main queue.

Comment: Are you initializing your self.mutableSections? Remember all mutable objects must be initiallized

Answer (score 1):

Usually when "waiting a little fixes the problem", it's because you have an async problem.

**Something to check first** :

Make sure your reload code is called when you move back. Maybe your tableview didn't get emptied, but the array did. Moving back would let you scroll the old content (still loaded) but the delegate methods won't be able to create new cells because the array is now empty.

If you wait, your async method does it's job and the array is now full again, which makes everything work fine.

**Possible solution :**

Empty then reload the tableview in `viewWillAppear`. This will cause a visual flash of the tableview going empty and then full again. It will also scroll you to the first element. That being said, it's really easy and fast, and with a spinner it will appear much smoother.

**Other possible solution :**

Keep the data loaded after leaving the page, so when you come back it's still there. You can use anything that will keep the data loaded while in the app. It could be a singleton class that stays instantiated, or save in a database and reload from it (it's much faster than straight up loading from the internet), or anything that you can think of.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Do you know how I can turn this line RecordManager *recordManager = [[RecordManager alloc] initWithRecord:self.record restaurant:self.restaurant sender:self.navigationController]; 
into a sharedInstance?

Comment: I get how sharedInstances work but never done with variables like self.record and self.restaurant in this case.